# Simple XML with Retrofit gradle issue

Tags: android, gradle, simple-framework

I faced the problem while compile simple xml converter for retrofit:

> Warning:Dependency xpp3:xpp3:1.1.3.3 is ignored for debug as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.
>   In case of problem, please repackage it with jarjar to change the class packages

I checked another answers to understand common solution, like inserting

```
  compile ('com.squareup.retrofit:converter-simplexml:1.9.0') {
    exclude group: 'xpp3', module: 'xpp3'
    exclude group: 'stax', module: 'stax-api'
    exclude group: 'stax', module: 'stax'
}
```

(or without `group` type), `multiDexEnabled true` or cleaning the project.

But the problem still appears. I guess it can be tied with jdk 1.8 version or may be something tricky I am not sure of.

gradle.build

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.neenbedankt.android-apt'


android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.task.projectname"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}


buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
  }
}


dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile ('com.squareup.retrofit:converter-simplexml:1.9.0') {
    exclude group: 'xpp3', module: 'xpp3'
    exclude group: 'stax', module: 'stax-api'
    exclude group: 'stax', module: 'stax'
}

compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.4.0'
compile 'org.simpleframework:simple-xml:2.7.1'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.4'

// other dependencies
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: I think this may not resolve the issue but do you mind trying with 23.0.2 buildToolsVersion quickly?

Comment: @cgr, I have tried with 23.0.2, but unfortunately, it's not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be weird, but when I have deleted converter dependency, it works well.

```
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:converter-simplexml:1.9.0'
```